Confusing triple pole single throw switch diagram
I can't seem to grasp this switch diagram to figure out how to wire it up.

How I read this is there are 4 positions for the slide to be in, shorting 1&2, 2&3 (default), 3&4,4&5. The dotted lines make me think that there are only two circuits (2/4 & 1/3/5) which would make all switch positions functionally the same, so I'm clearly missing something.
What I want is this functionality
.
The physical switch seems to suggest a single common with 3 connectors since one pin is separated from the other 3:

(though now I have a bigger picture it looks like the space is just one pin cut off, so maybe that is a clue.
The included schematic doesn't clear things up either:

pins 5&6 appear to be the chassis, but I am at a total loss as to how I should connect the switch in.
My current hypothesis is that the switch does not do the functionality I want, and perhaps I do understand the diagram, but then my question be what could this switch be for?
part: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Slide-Switches_SHOU-HAN-SK13D07VG5_C393948.html
datasheet: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_1912111437_SHOU-HAN-SK13D07VG5_C393948.pdf

Do you have the switch at hand? You could beep it out.

You got the part right about the diagram being confusing.

The functionality you want is the functionality you have already. From left to right, I will refer to the terminals as 1, C (common), 2, and 3. The positions are 1 connected to C, 2 connected to C, and 3 connected to C; your hypothesis about the cut-off pin is correct but I would still use a multimeter to verify.
The switch is shorting, so 1 and 2 will briefly be connected together when moving between positions, as will 2 and 3.

Ahh, so the thick blue line in the first diagram represents the short between physical pins 2(which is cut off) and 3. The dotted line area above is reference the different wiper positions, I was thinking the thick bottom line was the wiper.

Yep, you got it! And to reiterate, a "shorting" designation means that the non-common pins from adjacent positions will briefly be connected together as the slide moves between them. Non-shorting models should be available in the same configuration.
